# WPF animation follows the correct path but it's off in space

Tags: wpf, animation, path, geometry, transformation

here's what it looks like:
http://screencast.com/t/4cd1yQJReXt

the little ship image is suppose to follow the path you chart out for it. And it does work - it follows the path but it start at the wrong place. I can't figure out what's wrong with my animation and I've went through the code many times now. The XAML of the application is very simple all the elements are contains within
Canvas Name="Canvas1" Background="Black"

and this canvas is a child element of 
Window

And below is the code that does the animating. I know for a fact that lines I'm feeding it are correct. It's just that their reference point is somehow messed up.It's supposed to be Canvas1 but it's not.

```
            NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());

            MatrixTransform buttonMatrixTransform = new MatrixTransform();
            ship1.RenderTransform = buttonMatrixTransform;

            this.RegisterName("ButtonMatrixTransform", buttonMatrixTransform);

            PathGeometry animationPath = new PathGeometry();
            PathFigure pFigure = new PathFigure();
            pFigure.StartPoint = new Point(pathnodes.ElementAt<Line>(0).X1, pathnodes.ElementAt<Line>(0).Y1);

            PolyLineSegment ls = new PolyLineSegment();

            foreach (Line l in pathnodes)
            {
                ls.Points.Add(new Point(l.X1, l.Y1));
                ls.Points.Add(new Point(l.X2, l.Y2));
            }

            pFigure.Segments.Add(ls);      
            animationPath.Figures.Add(pFigure);

            animationPath.Freeze();

            MatrixAnimationUsingPath matrixAnimation =
                new MatrixAnimationUsingPath();

            matrixAnimation.IsOffsetCumulative = false;

            matrixAnimation.PathGeometry = animationPath;
            matrixAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            matrixAnimation.DoesRotateWithTangent = true;

            Storyboard.SetTargetName(matrixAnimation, "ButtonMatrixTransform");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(matrixAnimation,
                new PropertyPath(MatrixTransform.MatrixProperty));

            Storyboard pathAnimationStoryboard = new Storyboard();
            pathAnimationStoryboard.Children.Add(matrixAnimation);

            pathAnimationStoryboard.Begin(this);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't view your video :O(  But, could it be to do with RenderTransformOrigin not being set?  Normally when I'm doing transforms, I set the RTO to 0.5, 0.5 so that the origin is in the centre of the object.